# Remote debugging a failing DNS resolution?

Tags: dns

A friend of mine is in a remote location and cannot access a specific website that is however fully functioning.

It affects all his PCs at his location so I think a configuration/HOSTS file can be ruled out.

He can access other domains hosted on the same server under the same IP address.

When trying to ping the remote domain he gets a "Ping request could not find host". 
Direct access to the IP address works fine.

I guess he could access the domain (under windows) by manually editing his HOSTS file, but also his iPad and so on are affected.

The Domain is with aa major hoster/registrar, so I am a bit puzzled where this issue can come from and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he's using his ISPs DNS server it could have a stale DNS record. If he has access to his router he can change his DNS server to point to one that has the correct record for instance, Google's DNS 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4. Otherwise he'll have to contact the administrator of his DNS server to have the record updated.